# What should I think of when making an internal API public?

Tags: web-development, api, api-design

An internal API I've built will soon be consumed by a third party.

Should I open the current internal API to the public, or should I create a new API endpoints for external access?

Comment: Is your current api suitable for the requirement?

Answer (score 7):

You should definitely create new API endpoints for third party access, as some of the nonfunctional requirements are bound to be different.  For example,

- External APIs tend to have less frequent maintenance releases
- External API interfaces cannot be revised without joint approval
- Security requirements may be different
- Performance and availability requirements may be different
- Your abilility to grasp the impact of even small code changes is greatly lessened, as some of the code that consumes your logic is outside your company
- You may find new compatibility issues
- The third party may ask you to make some changes just for them

Also,

- You have to write release notes now (ugh!)

It's best to make the break now.  If you didn't originally imagine your API to be in a stranger's hand, it's probably not designed to be that way.

Take this opportunity to tidy up your interfaces and DTOs so that they are more likely to make sense to someone who has never seen them.  You are probably the one who is going to have to answer questions later, so may as well save yourself some work and try to make the API as intuitive as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you shouldn't be asking the question in the first place. There are few reasons for an API to not being public from the beginning, while there are important benefits, in terms of security, to open the API to public as soon as the first stable version is released.

Now that you are in a situation where you have to ask the question, there are a few elements which may help you decide:

- Is the API using the standards? A REST API relying on swagger is much more user-friendly than an API which uses an in-house, undocumented protocol. If you're in the second case, forget about using the API as-is. Create an intermediary which will expose the features through REST and/or SOAP, and readdress them to the internal API.
- If the API is constantly changing, it can hardly be opened to public. A public API interface cannot change once per day or per week: it should be relatively stable. Once the public endpoint starts to be used, you have to provide support for enough time. This means that you have to implement versioning strategy, and have to think twice before pushing a new version to production. Underlying errors could be corrected, but errors at the interface level will haunt you for months or years.
- Was the API written with security in mind? Often, developers rely on the fact that since something is internal, it doesn't have to be secure (as if no employees would want to harm the company one day.) Before exposing such API to public, you have to recheck **every** call, every parameter, to see how the API [mis]behaves.
- If you've reinvented the wheel when implementing the authentication mechanism, forget about opening the API to the public. You probably did the authentication part wrong, and you'll discover it the hard way.
- How is it handling DOS and DDOS attacks? If under DDOS attack, can you still access other resources, such as the system logs?

Comment: -1 for the first paragraph.